# Sidebar displayed incorrectly on Chrome until refresh

Tags: css, google-chrome, page-layout

Most people come here with websites being displayed incorrectly in IE; I have a website that works on Firefox and IE but not Chrome.

The website is displayed incorrectly on Chrome (see the image), the two widgets "Get it now" and "Social" should be on the right side, as a sidebar. What is interesting is that this happens only when the page is first opened. If I refresh it or navigate to another page, everything is back to normal and never happens again until I open the page again in a new tab.

The widgets are in a div with the following CSS properties:

```
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
width: 240px;
```

Do you have any idea why this happens?

If you want to investigate the page's source, you can do it at http://knowinc-the-game.com

The site in Chrome:

[image]

The site in IE:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using like a margin-left? Or maybe a float? Maybe even using left: